# How to make Visual Studio Code remember previous commit messages?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently started using Microsoft's open-source Visual Studio Code IDE for developing web projects, shifting from Eclipse. I find VSCode highly intuitive and very simple to use.

But one feature I miss in VSCode is that the IDE's inability to remember commit messages (or have I not explored enough?!). Unlike Eclipse, which populates a dropdown list of historical commit messages, we have to manually enter commit messages in VSCode every time we commit our changes.

- Is there any VSCode extension available for this purpose?
- Can I make any entry in `settings.json` so that older commit messages
  are retrieved automatically?

**Any help would be highly appreciated.**

Comment: It seems that it's still (Nov. 2018) not possible, there is an open feature request at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26952

Answer (score 43, accepted):

VSCode 1.51 (Oct. 2020) does have a similar feature: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd>:

---

VSCode 1.81, Aug. 2023, [still-dreaming-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172274/still-dreaming-1) mentions in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445199/how-to-make-visual-studio-code-remember-previous-commit-messages/64641604#comment135862243_64641604) that:

> Now, you don't even need to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, just the <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd>.
> If the cursor is at the start of the box, which it will be initially since it is blank, you can just press the up arrow.

---

> ### [Source Control input box saves commit message history](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b90c7662cebb51d859506135a03f1ff459f1c743/release-notes/v1_51.md#source-control-input-box-saves-commit-message-history)
>
> This addresses a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26952) to navigate SCM commit history.
>
> Press `kb(scm.viewPreviousCommit)` and `kb(scm.viewNextCommit)` to display the prior and next commits, respectively.
> To move directly to the first and last position of the input box, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> in conjunction with the corresponding arrow key.
>
> Build off of past commit messages and look back in the history without losing your drafted message.
>
> [image: After typing a message in the SCM input box, then staging and committing changes, pressing the up arrow reveals the message that was just committed.]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. @BiscuitBoy can you change it, please?

Comment: Let's just say "Alt+ Arrow up" for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @FabienHaddadi True. I have edited the answer to make that more visible.

Comment: Now you don't even need to use the Alt key, just the up arrow. If the cursor is at the start of the box, which it will be initially since it is blank, you can just press the up arrow.

Answer (score 19):

No need for a separate extension or something like that. Git can handle this via commit templates and VSCode supports them already.

For example, assuming you have a *unix-like* and are in the root of your repository:

```
echo "My fancy commit message" > .mycommitmsg.txt
git config --local commit.template .mycommitmsg.txt
```

From there, VSC will automatically use the content of .mycommitmsg.txt.

Second step is to fill this message file with the content of your last commit. That can be achieved with Git hooks, in your case you want the post-commit hook.

Create/edit the file `.git/hooks/post-commit` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "`git log -1 --pretty=%s`" > .gitmessage.txt
```

Don't forget to make it executable:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-commit
```

From there, everything should work as you described. The post-commit hook will automatically fill the message file with the content of your last message and VSC uses the new message as soon as you commit.

Comment: I work with Windows7. Can you please add the Windows commands too?

Comment: Windows commands should be the same, I used this with Windows 10 and it works as described

Comment: Shouldn’t the file in `post-commit` be '.mycommitmsg.txt', not '.gitmessage.txt'?

Comment: No need for a separate extension, just:
- Create a file
- Modify your git config
- Create a git hook
- Make sure your sh executable
- Repeat this for all your projects.

Tell me more.

Comment: To complicated. VonC answer is the easy way.

Answer (score 6):

there's an extension that might be interesting for some people:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JanBn.git-last-commit-message

I've just installed it before knowing about @kwood's answer, given that it helped me for a bit , I'm leaving this as a secondary option.

Comment: that said, I find the accepted answer much more elegant and definitively should be the go to method until they implement it inside vscode itself!

Comment: This extension now only partially works (probably due to the official support added for message history).