# Why does the COMMIT_EDITMSG open when I try to commit in vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Up until now, I can commit all my changes without any complications in VS Code. Now, when I try to commit my changes by clicking the little 'tick' on the top right corner of the 'Source Control' tab, a file named 'COMMIT_EDITMSG' shows up on the editor, and the Source Control panel remains in the loading state and nothing happens.

I don't know why this suddenly happened but I didn't do anything.

Is there a solution for this issue?

This is the file content:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   pages/support-topics.vue
#
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I just started getting this as well. Something surely changed in the default settings with a recent update.

The solution seems to be to turn off this setting

`git.useEditorAsCommitInput`

To change this, go to:

File > Preferences > Settings > search "git.useEditorAsCommitInput" then untick

Comment: It was introduced in the June 2022 1.69 update: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_author-commit-message-using-an-editor

Comment: Where  is that setting ?

Comment: File > Preferences > Settings > search "git.useEditorAsCommitInput" then untick

Answer (score 31):

When you make a commit, Git needs a commit message.  In order to get that commit message, Git will invoke your editor with a file called `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, which is where you write the message, saving the file and closing it.  Once you've done that, Git will take that message, strip out the comments, and use it as the commit message for your commit.

In that context, this is working as designed, and you just need to enter the commit message for your commit.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But it didin't showed me the file before, i was entering the commit message on the command palette.

Comment: Thank you for providing the true answer to this question: (make any necessary edits to the commit message and) **just close the file**.

Comment: What a bizarre interface.  It actually locked me out of editing the input where I forgot to add the commit message initially, and expected me to know I was supposed to edit, save, and close this strange file instead?  Had to find this answer just to know what to do!

Comment: I was hoping maybe this feature would allow you to use the same commit message as last commit or something, but nope.  Always gives you a new file.  Is there any way to do that in VS Code?  Show a history of commit messages and/or choose the same one as last time?  Edit: sorry, should have googled first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445199/how-to-make-visual-studio-code-remember-previous-commit-messages

Comment: You can do that with `git commit -C HEAD --reset-author` if you want.  If you want to edit it as well, then use `--edit` in addition.

Comment: I was really frustrated with this and for the changes to take effect I just had to close the file

Comment: @bk2204 Thank you for your reply. Was this information in the corresponding Release notes?

Comment: This is the way Git has worked for at least a decade and the way it works with every other editor.  If VS Code has ever done anything different, then that would be up to them to document, and a departure from normal Git behaviour.  I don't use VS Code (instead I use Vim), so I can't say either way.

Comment: If I close the file, I get "Commit operation was cancelled due to empty commit message.", even if I modify the text. So, in that case where closing the file doesn't solve the problem anymore, how is that commit message supposed to be written? <b>Edit:</b> got it: just write anything without a ```#``` (and then save and close)

Answer (score 4):

Try finding the Git settings within VS Code's settings:

-> **Git: Use Editor As Commit Input**

You just need to turn this off to avoid that pop up.

Answer (score 0):

It only does that if you do not type in a comment for your commit.

If you're executing the commit in the terminal use:

```
git commit -m "[commit comment here]"
```

to add a commit comment and avoid the EDITMSG from popping up

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).